# Implicit Conversion Not Working for Dynamic Type

Tags: c#-4.0, implicit-conversion, dynamic-typing

I am running into a problem when trying to implicitly convert one of my dynamic types. There are two assemblies with definitions similar to the following:

Configuration.dll:

```
public class ConfigurationValue : DynamicObject  
{
    public ConfigurationValue(string val)
    {
        //...
    }

    //...  

    public static implicit operator string(ConfigurationValue val)  
    {  
        return val.ToString();  
    }  
}
```

There is another class in this dll called `Configuration` with a member variable called `Instance` (to make the class singleton). This variable holds the `ConfigurationValue` instances in a dictionary and is of type dynamic. This allows me to do this following:

Server.dll:

```
//...

if (Configuration.Instance.SecurityLevel != "Insecure")
{
    //...
}
```

Assuming that SecurityLevel is in the dictionary. 
This if statement appears verbatim in my code and always fails with the following error:

> {"Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' and 'string'"}

Previously, when these two classes were in the same assembly, this code worked fine. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem, a little embarrassing actually, I forgot to change the container class for `ConfigurationValue` (e.g. the type of `Configuration.Instance`) from internal to public when I moved it to the new assembly, so of course the type couldn't be resolved and the implicit conversion was not found

Comment: You should mark it as answered even though you answered it yourself.

Comment: I was planning to but it made we wait three days and i forgot. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Grml I ran into the same thing with a non public class and this problem. Glad I found this!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var SecurityLevel = new ConfigurationValue("Insecure");
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Unfortunately, this is inapplicable in this case, though it would solve the problem as stated in the code of the first post. I simplified the code a lot, so let me clarify what exactly I'm trying to do.

I have another class `Configuration` with a static variable `Instance` (singleton) that is of type dynamic. This `Instance` field holds the configuration values so I can do something like this:
`if (Configuration.Instance.SecurityLevel != "Insecure")`
This is th if statement that is failing